# trying to return integer in reverse (without recursion)

Tags: java, runtime-error, reverse, parseint

i'm trying to print the reverse of a given integer. the function must take in an integer and return an integer (w/o recursion or printing each number as a string individually). this is what I've got but it's not working:

```
class Solution {
public int reverse(int x) 
{
    String numStr = "";
    while (x > 0)
    {  
        numStr = numStr + Integer.toString(x % 10);
        x /= 10;
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(numStr);
}
}
```

i'm getting a runtime error for my return statement. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is that runtime error?

Comment: its: Line 10: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Comment: The exception is descriptive. That means your string pass to `Integer.parseInt()` is an empty string, i.e., `""`. Are you passing an integer less than 1 to `reverse()`?

Comment: I did not get the exception after several run. What did you use as input?

Comment: ohh that might be the problem - I'm not sure because I'm just practicing with leetcode but I don't know all the values they are using - thank you!

Comment: @Liz Give `x = 0` a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `String` here, just accumulate each digit and multiply the current value by 10 (to shift right). Also, your method can be `static`. Like,

```
public static int reverse(int x) {
    int r = 0;
    while (x > 0) {
        r = (r * 10) + (x % 10);
        x /= 10;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a error for the value 0. Java can´t parse string "" to a int. Initialize the string value to "0".

On the other hand, you can simplify the method:

```
class Solution {
        public int reverse(int x) 
        {
            String digitsChain = Integer.toString(x);           
            return Integer.valueOf(StringUtils.reverse(digitsChain));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the case when x is 0. If x is 0, the string will be empty. When you call return Integer.parseInt(numStr), where numStr is empty string, it will cause the error.

So, if you add an if statement to check the edge case, it should be fine

```
    public static int reverse(int x) 
    {
        if(x == 0) return 0;
        String numStr = "";
        while (x > 0)
        {  
            numStr = numStr + Integer.toString(x % 10);
            x /= 10;
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(numStr);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
class Solution {
    public static int reverse(int x)
    {
    String numStr = "";
    while (x > 0)
    {
        numStr = numStr + Integer.toString(x % 10);
        x /= 10;
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(numStr);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int answer = reverse(12345);
    System.out.print(answer);
    }
}
```

I just made your method static and your code is working fine for me giving the following output:

54321
Process finished with exit code 0